# C# decode binary web socket frame

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, binary, frame

Actually I'm trying to analyse the communication between firefox (websocket wss) and a website in order to simulate the client through my PHP Script. First of all, I tried to read all the sockets through the socket inspector but it's TLS encrypted (it would have been too easy otherwise haha).

With MITM Proxy, I could now decrypt all the traffic including the web socket (wss) but unfortunately it seems to be binary data and I'm unable to decode it.

/ Edit : to be clear TLS isn't a problem at att thanks to MITM proxy, the main problem is the fact that the web socket frame is encoded in binary and i'm trying to translate it in string (/human-readable text) to know and read the conversation between my browser and the server

[image]

By using C# I tried to decode the binary in a string, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

```
String sourceHex = "000000000000000000746a2a35e11296a3da439c0a31337fc6";
        
string[] bytes = sourceHex.Select((x, i) => new { 
       x = x, index = i 
}).GroupBy(x => x.index / 2).Select(x => x.First().x.ToString() + x.Last().x.ToString()).ToArray(); 

byte[] results = bytes.Select(x => byte.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray(); 
        
results = results.Select(x => (x < 0x20 || x >= 0x80) ? (byte)46 : (byte)x).ToArray();

string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);

File.WriteAllText(@"string.txt", message);
```

Output :

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to decode(/decrypt) the frames between firefox and the website ? If you found a beginning of way on github or another don't hesitate because I searched for that without any success.

I tried wireshark without any succes, the same thing for FiddlerClassic and the C# isn't working, I have to admit that I'm blocked.

Thanks for reading, enjoy all your week
Respectfully

Comment: I think you are missing an important part of "what is TLS" and how it works.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli may be my question isn't clear and I apologize but thanks to MITM proxy or even Fiddler, the web socket (through wss) is in clear, there is no more TLS. My question is how to decode a web socket frame (from binary to string), TLS isn't a problem

Comment: if it's encoded is because is certificates in the server/client side, transmission by socket is not encoded. You should have the certificate and work with it, you should learn about TLS and this case, i pressume, httpS

Comment: TLS is TCP messages that are sent before the http request is transmitted.  You cannot get the TLS using Websocket.

Comment: I vote to close this question because has a lot of absence of previous knowledge (that can be learn with any search) on how TCP works and how TLS works. Is too broad at this level.

Comment: But guys, @LeandroBardelli as I said and edited my question, there is no TLS at all : I previously said that I'm using MITMproxy, so the tls traffic is DECRYPTED, I just want not DECRYPT but DECODE the binary websocket frame. Do you understand or I'm not clear, I apologize. My socket transmission is decrypted, but the format is binary and I'm trying to CONVERT/TRANSLATE binary to text

Comment: @jdweng As I said I have the web socket decrypted by MITMproxy (even Wireshark do the job perfectly with SSLKEYLOGFILE). My problem is that the decrypted frame is a socket in binary format, I want to translate that binary to text

Comment: Use following :             string[] bytes = sourceHex.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, index = i }).GroupBy(x => x.index / 2).Select(x => x.First().x.ToString() + x.Last().x.ToString()).ToArray();
            byte[] results = bytes.Select(x => byte.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);

Comment: TCP communication is plenty plain. In other words, HTML is just the protocol for web messages through TCP.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli the websocket is in clear, that's why I'm talking about DECODING, and not DECRYPTING. I'm working on the solution of @ jdweng actually I will update soon, but I'm really trying not to decrypt but decode/translate the binary sent inside the websocket to text

Comment: @jdweng Thanks again for your time and your reply, I tested your code with a messagebox.Show at the end but It doesn't seem to work, like mine finally haha. It's not the conversation containing all the login/pass and finally messages sent, but it give me some "symbol"

Comment: @jdweng Okay I try to write message in a txt with File.WriteAllText and Encoding.UTF8. This time it's not blank as the MessageBox, but it's still "unreadable" with symbols :  it looks like that  https://ibb.co/NZCb0cg

Comment: My code works just puts real characters in place of the periods.  Adding following will filter the special characters : results = results.Select(x => (x < 0x20 || x >= 0x80) ? (byte)46 : (byte)x).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng Thank for your reply, I edited my post with your code, as you can see in the original post, the output keep contains unreadable "binary" symbol, any idea ? have a nice day

Comment: You can change the range of characters that will show a period.  It look like the character after the 13 is 0x7F.  So use (x < 0x20 || x >= 0x7F)

Comment: @jdweng thanks my friend it's working well. Have a nice week !